# react native expo crashes when trying to get ref for Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Hey my app crashes when i try to do this.

```
<Root ref={(navigatorRef) => {console.log(navigatorRef)}})>
```

i was following this guide

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

i am relatively new in expo. Can anyone tell me what am missing

Comment: What is that `Root`?  Custom componenet? What is your stacktrace or error message?

Comment: the Root component is my Top Level Component for navigation. i am trying to get the ref as mentioned in the link doc. there is no error message. it gets build and then crashes.

Comment: Is that Android or ios?

Comment: am debugging in ios device using expo. i checked in ios simulator and there its not crashing